# Codeigniter mac os session issue

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter, session, mamp

I am new to MacOS.  I have Codeigniter system. It's working fine in the WAMP server. I copied the same system to MAMPP server MacOS. Login page is not working. I found actual error. Error was in the session writing. After 
redirect login page to success page session lost returning NULL value. 
I am using default Codeigniter config file:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: The obvious questions - have you checked/set permissions and ownership on the sessions directory [as described in the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#files-driver)? Are you sure `BASEPATH` is set and available in the config file?

Comment: set permission to all the directory getting same issue after redirect session null. BASEPATH correct there was a session temp files

Comment: In that case, you need to show us your code.

Comment: code working fine in the wamp server window problem is in the  mac

Comment: Have you set the file/folder permissions?

Comment: i have set read/write permission to all folders

Comment: in console, if you go to cache and do ll what does it show for the sessions folder?

Comment: found the solution, codeigniter version problem, i have changed the system folder now its working